# Lowercase 0x with uppercase iostream

Tags: c++, hex, iostream

It seems more elegant to use `std::showbase` instead of manually putting `"0x"` in front.

```
std::cout << std::hex << std::showbase << std::uppercase << 43794;
```

But is there an easy way to print `0xAB12` instead of `0XAB12`?

Comment: Doesn't look more elegant to me and coupled with the fact that it doesn't meet your requirements, I think you already have your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::cout << "0x" << std::uppercase << std::hex << 43794;
```